# Why won't my gas gauge fill past 3/4?

Tags: nissan, gasoline, gauges, sentra

I have a 2006 Nissan Sentra and no matter what gas station I go to, the gauge never moves past 3/4. What could be stopping it from filling all the way up?

Comment: Check the tank has not collapsed - used to happen on one model I remember...

Comment: There's a difference between the gauge not going past 3/4 and the tank not holding more than 3/4.  Do you know if the tank can still hold the original amount?  Does the gauge stop at 3/4 but you can continue to pump in lots of fuel?

Comment: The pump shuts off at 3/4, so it doesn't let me pump any more.

Comment: If you can't pump any more, either the tank has collapsed and reduced in volume, or the gauge is reading empty when the tank is still 1/4 full. If you take the gauge off the tank when it reads empty, you should be able to dip the tank to see how much fuel is still in there.

Comment: It is either the sending unit in the fuel tank next to the pump (they use the same bracket) or the fuel gauge behind the dash panel (where the speedometer is). I replaced both units in the field. You can test the sending unit with a voltmeter, but I don't recall what is normal reading for a typical unit. The Nissan Manual will have the specification. Can you go to a Nissan dealership and ask them to look it up for you for testing? If you recently had a fuel pump replaced, then it is likely the sending unit mounted incorrectly/disturbed because they are on the same bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Your float in gas tank has either got something stuck in it keeping it from going on to full tank, or it's got a dead spot and your sensor's not reading. More than likely your vehicle hit a pothole and that bent the dial just enough to keep it from going to top.

To fix it, you'll have to pull the float out of the tank.  Make sure when you raise float around all way up the little ATM on side goes to top too. That's what reads how much gas in tank: float arm goes up, little arm on side runs up and down the sensor for reading gas measurement. The other fix would be to replace the float in the tank. Good luck!

(Alternately, you can sometimes fill the tank up as much as it can go, then hit a little pothole or speedbump.  If it's just stuck, that may jar it loose -- I've done it.)